# Run a Vue function to fetch array data inside a v-for when a Bootstrap collapse is clicked

Tags: vue.js

Good day forks. Please help. I want to Run a Vue function to fetch array data inside a v-for when a Bootstrap collapse is clicked. So I have an array of items with (id, title, description etc) attributes. Then for each of the item, it has an array of sub-items. So I want to fetch the sub-items when I click the item and shows in a bootstrap collapse div as follows:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <p>
     <a :href="'#' + item.id" data-toggle="collapse">{{
          item.item_name
        }}</a>
      </p>
      <div class="collapse" :id="item.id">
        <div v-html="getSubItems(item.id)">
          <p v-for="sub_item in sub_items" :key="sub_item.id">
            {{ sub_item.sub_item_name }}
          </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 5:44 Status
          <span class="label label-success pull-right">{{
            item.item_status ? "Done" : "Pending"
          }}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
```

And the JavaScript is as follows:

```
export default {
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      id: 1,
      items: [],
      sub_items: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://ip/api/v1/items")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.topics = response.data.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
  methods: {
    getSubItems: function(item_id) {
      return axios
        .get("http://ip/api/v1/sub-items/" + item_id)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.sub_items = response.data.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Why voted me down? Any violation of Stackoverflow reason? Please explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was you, I would respond to a click event on the anchor tag to get the sub_items.

[v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) is used to render raw HTML which is probably why your code doesn't work.

I've created a snippet below (without the axios) to show one way you could get it working.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      id: 1,
      items: [],
      sub_items: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getItems();
  },
  methods: {
    getItems: function() {
      this.items = [{
        id: 1,
        item_name: "Test Item"
      }];
    },
    getSubItems: function(item_id) {
      this.sub_items = [{
        id: 1,
        sub_item_name: "Test Sub Item"
      }];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <p>
      <a :href="'#panel-' + item.id" data-toggle="collapse" @click="getSubItems(item.id)" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">{{
          item.item_name
        }}</a>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" :id="'panel-' + item.id">
      <div>
        <p v-for="sub_item in sub_items" :key="sub_item.id">
          {{ sub_item.sub_item_name }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 5:44 Status
        <span class="label label-success pull-right">{{
            item.item_status ? "Done" : "Pending"
          }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shoejep. You saved my day. Thanks for taking the time to answer! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a :href="'#' + item.id" data-toggle="collapse" @click="getSubItems(item)">{{
          item.item_name
        }}</a>
    //
   getSubItems: function(item) {
if (!item.subItems){
      return axios
        .get("http://ip/api/v1/sub-items/" + item_id)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.sub_items = response.data.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    }
  }
```

only fetch subitems if you don't already have. So you should make a check in the function if you have them.
 The simplest way I think would be to save the results on the item itself as item.subItems then once you open you don't need to open again